# Beamer: only<2> within uncover<1>

Tags: beamer

I have a nested `itemize` within another `itemize` on a Beamer frame. I'd like to create an overlay that wouldn't have the "Test 2" item on the first slide at all, but would have it on the second slide, with the "Test 1" item grayed out. I tried this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{cmap}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1> Test 1
\begin{itemize}
\item<only@2> Test 2
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But the "Test 2" item is grayed out on the second slide, which is not what I want. Could you please help me solve this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inner `itemize` is part of the first item of the outer one, so the transparency applied to that item applies to the whole inner list. You can apply it only to the text before the list manually.

Also, you probably want `visible@2` instead of `only@2` in order to preserve spacing between the overlays.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \uncover<1>{Test 1}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<visible@2> Test 2
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That way, the bullet point for the "Test 1" item is `visible` on the second slide, but if you wrap everything including `\item` inside `\uncover`, it works!